# How to suppress "Unsupported parameters" error in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, backwards-compatibility

I am using a the `quiet` parameter in the [`assert` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assert_module.html) for tasks where the output is too verbose. The `quiet` parameter was introduced in Ansible 2.8, but unfortunately, my code sometimes needs to run on Debian Buster, which still comes with Ansible 2.7.

In that case, Ansible fails with the fatal error "Unsupported parameters for (assert) module: quiet". Since this is only a cosmetic parameter, I want Ansible 2.7 to ignore this parameter and continue.

Is there a way to add this parameter in my task so that Ansible 2.8 is nice and quiet, but the task still runs in Ansible 2.7?

```
- name: Silent assert
  assert:
    that:
      - true
    quiet: yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [`omit` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#making-variables-optional) which can help in bypassing some parameters if they are not applicable. For this purpose, we can define a variable that will be set to `true` for Ansible version 2.8 or greater. Then this variable can be passed to the `quiet` parameter of `assert` module in combination with `omit`.

Example:

```yaml
  - set_fact:
      quiet_assert: true
    when: ansible_version.full is version('2.8', '>=')
  - assert:
      that:
      - true
      quiet: "{{ quiet_assert|default(omit) }}"
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought of `omit`. Much appreciated. For those who like (unreadable) one-liners, this works too, without a separate `set_fact`: `quiet: "{{ ansible_version.full is version('2.8', '>=') | ternary(true, omit) }}"`